# Does a rating system violate twitter display requirements?

Tags: twitter, requirements

I'm confused about the new [twitter display requirements](https://dev.twitter.com/terms/display-requirements).

**BACKGROUND**

I dynamically generate a page with a series of tweets based on their popularity. To the right of the tweets I have a like/dislike rating system which is used to determine the popularity of the tweet.

**QUESTIONS**

Am I allowed to place the like/dislike icons near the tweets?

Does the rating system violate any twitter developer rules?